# Rails 5.1 .any? and .exists? causes unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with Rails and have encountered an issue with a model that references a table defined in schema.rb as:

`create_table "test_table", primary_key: ["somthing", "somthing1"]...`

I believe this represents a composite primary key. However, I'm uncertain about how Rails generates this via schema:dump.

When using with this model, I can successfully retrieve all records using `TestTable.all`, which returns the expected data. But when I try to use `TestTable.all.exists?`, I encounter the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name '"somthing", "something1"'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  1 AS one FROM [testtable]  ORDER BY [testtable].["something", "somthing1"] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1)`

This happends for any use of `.any?` and `.exists?`

To address this, I attempted to use the `composite_primary_keys` gem.

`self.primary_keys = :something, :something1`

Unfortunately, this resulted in the same error.

I'm at a loss for how to proceed. It seems like Rails is directly using the primary key as defined in the array in the schema. It's worth noting that this database was pre-existing, and there aren't many migration files available. I'm not sure if this could be causing the issue, but I thought it might be relevant.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic: What is advantage of such composite primary key? May be it's better to migrate to usual PK and create unique constraint on these two columns?

Comment: Uhhh. Rails *just* added composite primary keys in Rails 7.1, which as of time of writing this comment is still in beta. You can see it yourself in the changelog here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/7_1_release_notes.html#composite-primary-keys. 
The way you're writing makes it seem like you didn't write this code. Was composite_primary_keys already installed?

Comment: @BenGarcia I installed and added the composite keys gem. Im trying to slowly upgrade to rails 6. This is a rather old code base.

Comment: Did you try [reordering your Gemfile](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/issues/596)?

Comment: @sneakyfishies was the primary key syntax that you saw there before or after you added the composite keys gem? It's confusing as to what's going on here, as you make it sound like you "came across" this schema. There are too many unknowns wrt who wrote, gems in the runtime, etc.